# Linear Hashing for Data Storage

Tags: database, hash, storage

Assume I am using [linear hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_hashing), assume 3 number per block and no overflow buffer. I want to insert 100 zero. It seems that no matter how many splits I do, the number cannot be inserted. How linear hashing handle that? I know the data is extremely shew in that case but I just want to know how linear hashing handle it. Or that is the limitation of linear hashing.

Comment: any idea about the worst case of linear hashing?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct - the data cannot be accommodated.  If there are no overflow blocks, and more hash collisions than can fit in the initial block, the data cannot be stored.  Presumably the implementation would signal failure in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables are amortized constant time, but worst-case linear time. I would back up a hash table by a classic B-tree, as a single "overflow bucket", which more or less guarantees a logarithmic time. Once a bucket is full, further contents for that bucker are placed into the B-tree. If your buckets can accomodate at least 3 records, and the average occupancy of the hash table is kept within 30%, less than 1% records will overflow. And if your hash function becomes compromised (a lot of collisions from  malicious records), B-tree will come to rescue